# Facing inertnal server error. Why this happens?

Tags: internal-server-error, odoo-13

I have recently restart the odoo service then enter the url 'http://localhost:8069/'. Then I am facing the following error:

**"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application"**

I have rechecked my code and found no error. Then why this happens??

My Log Details:

[Log Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAqN9.png)

Comment: Check the logs, you'll have the complete error message there

Comment: I will send you Screenshot of log.

Comment: I have edit my question and add an log details. Please check

Comment: Can you give log after just restarting odoo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They fixed the issue, You don't have to downgrade your python version. Just Update your Server code.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 20.04, is using by default python version 3.8.2 and it upgraded to 3.8.5 and odoo is not support to that version. Odoo 13 supports python version 3.7. Degrade your python version to 3.7 then it starts working.

Thank You